# The Complexity of "The Baby Shark Song".

Tags: asymptotics, recreational-mathematics, information-theory, music-theory

*This question is just for fun. I hope it's received in the same goofy spirit in which I wrote it.*

I just had the pleasure of reading Knuth's *"The Complexity of Songs"* and I thought it'd be hilarious if someone could do an analysis of the complexity of an infinite version of [*"The Baby Shark Song"*](https://youtu.be/XqZsoesa55w) or two, similar to the one done in *ibid.* on *"O' McDonald had a Farm"*.

### Here are the lyrics:

"Baby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Baby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Baby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Baby shark!

"Mommy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Mommy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Mommy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Mommy shark!

"Daddy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Daddy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Daddy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Daddy shark!

"Grandma shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Grandma shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Grandma shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Grandma shark!

"Grandpa shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Grandpa shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Grandpa shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Grandpa shark!

"Let's go hunt, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Let's go hunt, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Let's go hunt, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Let's go hunt!

"Run away, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Run away, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Run away, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Run away!

"Safe at last, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Safe at last, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Safe at last, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

Safe at last!

"It's the end, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

It's the end, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

It's the end, doo doo doo doo doo doo.

It's the end!"

### Possible schema:

Let $D=\text{"doo"}^6$.

Let $R(x)=x\, D,\, x\, D,\, x\, D,\, x$.

Let $$\begin{align}
S_b&=\text{"baby shark"},\\
S_m&=\text{"mommy shark"},\\
S_d&=\text{"daddy shark"},\\
S_{gm}&=\text{"grandma shark"},\\
S_{gp}&=\text{"grandpa shark"},\\
H&=\text{"let's go hunt"}, \\
R_a&=\text{"run away"}, \\
S&=\text{"safe at last"}, \\
E&=\text{"it's the end"}.
\end{align}$$

Let $U(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)=R(a)R(b)R(c)R(d)R(e)R(f)R(g)R(h)R(i)$.

A song of order $n$ would be defined as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{S}_0&=\epsilon, \\
\mathscr{S}_n&=U(S_b,S_m, S_d, S_{gm}, S_{gp}, H, R_a, S,E)\mathscr{S}_{n-1}
\end{align}$$

for $n\ge 1$.

And so on . .  .

### The Problem:

I'm not sure how to take it from there.

### Thoughts:

It should be simple. In fact, I think the complexity of the song, as defined, is just $O(1)$.

I'm not happy with the current schema, either. The $R(E)$ should go at "the end" instead of interspersed throughout for one thing.

### Alternatively . . .

> What would happen to the complexity of the song if we insist that, instead, we go from $R(\text{"baby shark"})$ to $R(\text{"grandpa shark"})$ as at the beginning but then, with $$V_\ell(S_{gm}, S_{gp})=R(G_\ell S_{gm})R(G_\ell S_{gp}),$$ where $G_\ell=\text{great}^\ell$ for $\ell\ge 1$, we just carry on with the $V_\ell$s?

Again, I suspect that it's $O(1)$, but I believe this much less than I do in the first case.

Please help :)

Comment: I for sure can't help you, but I just gotta say that I love this question (+1)

Comment: usually credited as achieving the extremum: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3svW8PM_jc

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20051226111159/http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/arvindn/misc/knuth_song_complexity.pdf

Comment: Only the dead can know peace from this song.

Comment: [Related: Message in Mathematics chatroom about "The Twelve Days of Christmas"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48265790#48265790)

Comment: You can always be inspired by computational versión s of complexity https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Answer (score 3):

[Computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) (which uses big-O notation) is for programs that take a variable input; it measures the time required to produce the output. [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) is for finding the shortest program with no input that produces a specific string; it measures the size of the program required to produce the output.  Pick a [universal Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) (programming language) and then look for the shortest program that produces the output; this is often referred to as "[code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)".  I would suggest [Shark](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Shark) as an appropriate language for this problem.